Readings to understand the genesis of 19th C continental philosophy
I'm curious to read a book length work that helps me understand something about the motivations of 19th c. continental philosophers. This might be a history-of-philosophy kind of book, or maybe a biography of the relevant philosophers, but I don't want to read a set of academic papers or something that's more like a textbook. Well, I would do that as a last resort, but I am hoping there's something more accessible than that that would do the trick.
I have no academic background in philosophy - what I know I have strung together from reading various popular books on philosophy (At The Existentialist Cafe, by Sarah Bakewell) perhaps being the latest,), "by listening to podcast episodes, and reading various magazine articles. In particular, I'm trying to understand why certain concepts like "Being" and "Will" were of such interest to 19th c. European philosophers, perhaps setting them apart from their most immediate forerunners, in the 2-3 centuries prior. I imagine that philosophers are motivated by problems they have seen their teachers and other elders "solve" and need improvement. Did Hegel, Schelling, Schopenhauer et al. have some particular unsolved problem in mind as they tried to work out things like Essence, Grounding, Spirit, and such like?
Based on my background, my best supposition is that these philosophers were trying to replace some kind of vacuum left behind by the diminishing value of theology in adequately explaining things, especially in a world being changed so much (for Europeans) by industrialization, science, and in general the Renaissance. Scripture couldn't adequately explain things so they had to step in to create a new vocabulary.
I state my conjecture only to give you all a sense of how much/little I know, so it could help you in guiding me to the right text.

Thinkers like Kant had already critiqued pure reason's limits of the previous 18th century's enlightenment period. The 19th-century philosophers you mentioned were inheritors of this critique and sought to go beyond Kant to address profound questions of existence, meaning, and freedom. Concepts like "Being," "Will," and "Spirit" became central as these philosophers sought to reframe metaphysics in a way that could rival religious narratives without necessarily depending on traditional theology, similar existentialists such as Kierkegaard, Nietzsche, and Dostoevsky also joined this critique...

Keep in mind that the analytic/continental split only solidified in 1930s so projecting it to the 19th century is a modernization. Not a book length, but Rosen has a long survey paper that focuses on common themes of 'continental philosophy' from Hegel onwards. For book length, there is Stone's Critical History of Nineteenth-Century Philosophy that also tries to "cut across authors".

For getting a handle on Kant there is some background on the concepts of essentia and existentia in chapters 2 & 3 here: The Basic Problems of Phenomenology (1927).

@DoubleKnot I would mark your answer as accepted if you posted it by itself.

Taking your penultimate paragraph — Philosophers were trying to replace some kind of vacuum... theology — as the point of departure,
your time frame seems off. From the Lutheran Reformation itself Christianity was diluted denatured and trivialized until 2 centuries later it had to collapse into secularism then atheism then world wars then dystopia today. I recommend Brad Gregory as elaboration and exegesis on this theme.
Also see this selection from an offbeat book that may be of interest:
Emphasis added by me as germane to your question

... brought about an outwardly similar development to what
would have occurred if the Christians had accepted Islam, as
Muslims hold that they ought to have done. The Muslim
contention is that when Christ told his disciples at the end
of his mission that he had still many things to declare to
them and that after he had left them the Comforter would
come who would not speak of himself but only what was
revealed to him, he was prophesying the coming of Mo¬
hammad and the revelation to him of the Quran. If Chris¬
tians had accepted this viewpoint Christianity would have
been converted into a world-sanctifying religion in the
seventh century a.d. instead of the seventeenth. However,
there would have been a vital difference, for Islam, while
creating a social organization, still retained paths for the full
spiritual development of the individual, which seem to be
lacking in the modern world. In any case a might-have-been
is an illusion, for events take their prescribed course and do
not happen by accident. Christ himself said no less when he
declared that ‘evil must needs come’. The course which
history has been taking in the last five centuries or so has
been towards a diminution and final rejection of spirituality,
and although it arose in the West and spread out from there
it has become world-wide.
It is no policy of this book to take sides between sects,
and it should be added that the founders of Protestantism had
certainly no idea that in cancelling Christ’s appeal for renun¬
ciation they were laying the axe to the tree of religion.
Indeed, no one would have been more surprised or indignant
if they had been told that the individual interpretation of the
Bible for which they were fighting would lead to eighteenth-
century rationalism, nineteenth-century agnosticism and
twentieth-century secularism1 , leaving no place for religion
except as private opinion; and yet this course of development
was inevitable, for once the spiritual essence of religion has
been lost the remainder begins to wither.
Buddhism and Christianity in the light of Hinduism
by
Arthur Osborne

1 ¿¿...and twenty-first century 10 zillion alternate realities dystopia??

-1 Lutheranism led to modern public education,  a German translation of the Bible, a ressertion of democratic values,  and forced a reform of the Catholic church including the Jesuits. Your narrative is detached from an understanding of the nuances of Christianity.

@JD No disagreement your points.  Including nuance.  It's the larger point I wish to underscore. Luther's actions (about the man and his intentions) — too nuanced for a brief discussion. Luther (1) split (2) rebelled (3) trivialized doctrine . 1 →zillions on Christianities with corresponding diminished gravitas. 3→ prevursor to modern dystopia on the intellectual/philosophical plane. Ultimately meaning-elision/evasion in analytic philosophy  2→ modern dystopia on the empirical, political level.  activism, cancel culture etc

@JD As for nuance, I will only say I'm probably closer to Luther than not just Catholics but most Protestants. Through most f my life J S Bach has been an icon of the most supreme possibilities of music. And Bach was a devoted Lutheran. So I'm surely not against Luther. Or even his actions (the popes he rebelled against were great a__h__les). But the continuing consequences for Christianity and humanity have been more deleterious than helpful. In any case thanks for explaining your -1

I think it would be better if people faced the 'vacuum'. The universe is big and empty except for some dust and stars, and completely pointless as far as we can tell. Yet, that knowledge doesn't affect my daily life at all. We would do better to see it and choose to do constructive things anyway than to try to hide under the rug. I don't understand why this is such a big issue for people.

@ScottRowe Man is a metaphysical being (dunno who exactly I'm quoting). Point is: Your comment above says Lets not indulge in metaphysics That's fine but it follows from the  principle No metaphysics!! — which hsppens to be a metaphysical principle. BTW I think youre wrong on the physics: Universe is empty implies No dark matter. Jury is certainly out on that one

Ok, well I don't see how "no metaphysics" is any different from "no Santa Claus". Zero is the most fundamental number, and NO is the first and most important word. Supposedly there is a church where carved over the entrance it says (like God's voice): "Remember, 'No' is an Answer" (to prayers). If we pray, "does God exist" and dying stars across the universe howl Noooooo then we should take heed. It's the only answer we'll get. (Gosh. What got in to him this morning?)
